# Rising factorials

Tags: factorial

Let  $a^{\bar{n}}$ be a rising factorial or Pochammer symbol and ${\Gamma(a)}$ be the Gamma function.
I want to ask if  $0^{\bar{0}}$=$1$ or not. As you know there is a relation between the rising factorial and The Gamma Function: $a^{\bar{n}}=\frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(a)}$ . I want to ask when a=n=0 can we claim $0^{\bar{0}}$=$\frac{\Gamma(0)}{\Gamma(0)}$ =$1$? I looked at some books. But I am a little bit complicated.
Thanks for your answers and references.

Answer (score 3):

The rising factorial is defined as $a^{\overline{n}} = \prod_{i=1}^n (a+i-1)$, so in particular, $a^{\overline{0}} = \prod_{i=1}^0 (a+i-1)$, which is an empty product - but an empty product is always 1, so so $a^{\overline{0}} = 1$.

Comment: Thank you . But is it also suitable for rising factorial in Hypergeometric series?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking - TTBOMK, the rising factorial is always defined the same way, so I'm not sure how hypergeometric series come in here?

Comment: I mean its always suitable. Thanks for your answer.