# The special case of Pochhammer Symbol at Zero?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, pochhammer-symbol

I am interested in a property of  Pochhammer Symbol. So I need an information about it.

Let  $a^{\bar{n}}$  Pochhammer symbol or rising factorial. As you know in the literature  $a^{\bar{0}}=1.$
I want to ask in a special case of $a=0$. For instance whether $0^{\bar{0}}$ or $0^{\bar{5}}$ are defined or not in literature.

In my opinion  $0^{\bar{0}}$=$1$ and $0^{\bar{5}}$=$0$ .

But when i have investigated about it, I am a little bit complicated becuase I have read in books of Rainville Special Functions in page 22. It is written as below:

For n is a natural number;

$\begin{aligned}(\alpha)^{\bar{n}} &=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(\alpha+k-1) \\ &=\alpha(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2) \cdots(\alpha+n-1), \quad n \geqq 1,  \\(\alpha)^{\bar{0}} &=1, \quad \alpha \neq 0 . \end{aligned}$

In another book of Mathai ve HauholdSpecial Functions for Applied scientists in page $1$:

$0^{\bar{5}}$ is not defined.

My open question; Can Pochhammer symbol or rising factorial be defined special case of zero?

My another question's link about this topic is  [Rising factorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328257/rising-factorials).

Thanks a lot for  your answers and references.

Comment: To me it appears straightforward from your definition that $0^{\bar{n}}=0$ for all $n$. Why would you not come to this conclusion?

Comment: @Joe yes firstly i was agree with you but after reading contradictory information in the books I mentioned above, i had a little disagreement. What is your reference? my other question what about the falling factorial?

Comment: Excuse me I meant all $n>0$. I have not looked at any reference. Fix $n>0$ a natural number. Then $a^{\bar{n}}$ is a polynomial in $a$, with a root at $a=0$ coming from the first factor, and hence $0^{\bar{n}}=0$. (Note that the expression is not a polynomial if $n$ varies). Perhaps somebody else has a reason why this argument does not make sense, however to me currently it is convincing.

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I fixed it. Your argument looks sensible. i will search it. but then what is n at zero to you?

Comment: In that case by your definition you have $0^{\bar{0}} =\prod_{k=1}^0(k-1)$ and this empty product would be equal to 1, however I would want to see how this matches up with other definitions before making a definitive statement here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(EDIT)

I would start with the ['extended' definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Properties) for any *real* value of $n$ :
$$\tag{1}x^{\bar{n}}=\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}$$
which should provide directly $x^{\bar{0}}=1$ (since $\Gamma(x)\not =0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and by analytic continuation for non positive integers as $\Gamma(x)$ becomes infinite)

Let's use $(1)$ too for $x^{\bar{n}}$ as $\,x\to 0$.

For $n>0$ the limit should give us $0^{\bar{n}}=0$ (because $\dfrac 1{\Gamma(x)}=x+\gamma x^2+O(x^3)\;$ to multiply by nearly $\Gamma(n)$)

For $n<0$ the results are more interesting :

- for $n$ not integer the results are $0$ again (as for $n>0$)
- for $n$ negative integer we get $\dfrac {(-1)^n}{(-n)!}$ (factorizing the numerator)

Should we consider the limit as $n\to 0$ then the result would be undefined since the limit would be between $1$ and $0$ depending of $x$ or $n$ going faster to $0$ (as $x\to 0$, $\dfrac 1{\Gamma(x)}\sim x$ so that forcing $n:=x$ would for example generate the limit $\dfrac 12$).
This written and if we *set* $n=0$ (instead of taking the limit as $n\to 0$) then we may apply our $x^{\bar{0}}=1$ result and obtain $0^{\bar{0}}=1$ (corresponding to our formula for negative integers) similar to the result for the ordinary power $0^{0}=1$ (and with the same reservations...).

Comment: Its nice approach. Thanks. In my opinion its really interesting that any book i read cant write in details about this question. Do you have any reference?

Comment: My usual reference for all things concerning the $\Gamma$ function is [Abramowitz and Steven's book](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm) or [Dlmf](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5). It is important to notice that $\dfrac 1{\Gamma(x)}$ is an entire and thus [well defined function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function).

Comment: Wolfram functions (Mathematica) consider too Pochhammer for negative $n$ [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/02/) and proposes $0^{\bar{0}}=1$ [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/03/02/)

Comment: Thanks for your references.

Comment: @user1062: I edited my answer with something possibly clearer! :-)

Comment: I think I understand better now:) Could it be that some books keep separate the zero case  because they need to be studied separately?

Comment: Concerning Mathai & Haubold's book for example they wrote too that $\dfrac 13 !=$ *not defined* a little before defining the $\Gamma$ function allowing answers for the whole complex plane. Concerning the Pochhammer symbol they choose to *define* $(b)_r$ supposing that $b\not = 0$ : the 'not defined' for $(0)_5$ Is a mere local consequence of their definition! I started with the extended definition for real values of $n$ so no problem for this definition!

Answer (score 3):

Fix $n>0$ a natural number. Then by your definition $a^\bar{n}$ is a polynomial in $a$ with a root at $a=0$ coming from the first factor, and hence $0^\bar{n}=0$. (Note that the expression is not a polynomial if $n$ varies).

For the case $n=0$ by your definition we have $0^{\bar{0}} =\prod_{k=1}^0(k-1)$ and this empty product is equal to 1. However I would want to see how this matches up with other definitions before making a definitive statement here.